# How to send an email with attachment using default email client in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, email-attachments, email-client, mapi

I am wondering if how it could be done. Is it possible to do it?

Here is my simple code:

```
Try
    MsgBox("Please wait this may takes time to load", vbInformation, "Mailing System")
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("mailto:" & txtEmailadd.Text)
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message & " Having some technical difficulties, kindly check if the email textbox has data in it", vbCritical, "System Advisory")
End Try
```

I want to add an attachment inside of this before the default client loads. Unfortunately, i don't find any answers in the web. Can you give some advice? Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to call the MailMessage.Attachments(). Here's the example code:

```
Dim MailMsg as New MailMessage
Dim loAttachment As Attachment = Nothing
Dim ls_email_attach as String
Dim server as String

ls_email_attach = "attach.xls"
server = "Mail server info"

//add the attachment
If Not ls_email_attach.Trim = "" Then
        loAttachment = New Attachment(ls_email_attach)
        loMailMsg.Attachments.Add(loAttachment)
End If

//send the email
MailMsg = New SmtpClient(server)
MailMsg.Send(loMailMsg)
```

Please see [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.attachments(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2) for reference.

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi shing, thank you for your reply. Im gonna try this thing.